# ROS topic and ROS INFO publishes different format for same data

Tags: yaml, ros, publish-subscribe, camera-calibration, rosnodejs

I am reading camera extrinsic parameter from a .yaml file and publishing it to a topic named extrinsic. After the node launched, I am getting the parameters and data published on the same terminal as a result from ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str()); on the same terminal where I launch the node. See the image below. The format here is same as in the .yaml file.

[Image shows data from ROS INFO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuOka.png)

But when using rostopic echo /extrinsic, I am getting the parameters and values in different format as shown below.

[rostopic echo shows data in different format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLy5v.png)

I need the data published to the topic "extrinsic" as the same format as I am getting from the ROS INFO stream. Please help me by suggesting the required update in the code below for achieving the same.

```cpp
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "std_msgs/Float64.h"

#include <sstream>

struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid()); // Get the user's home directory
std::string home_dir(pw->pw_dir);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "calibration_publisher");
  ros::NodeHandle n("~");
  YAML::Node params_node;
  std::string calibration_file, camera_frame;
  
  
  calibration_file = home_dir + "/.ros/camera_info" + ros::names::parentNamespace(n.getNamespace()) + "_extrinsics.yaml";
  std::cout << "Namespace " << ros::names::parentNamespace(n.getNamespace()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Calibration file "<< calibration_file << std::endl;

  //std::ifstream file_in;
  //file_in.open(calibration_file.c_str());
  
  params_node = YAML::LoadFile(calibration_file);
  
  if (!n.getParam("camera_frame", camera_frame))
  {
    ROS_ERROR("No camera frame parameter was passed to the calibration publisher");
    return -1;
  }
  
  for (auto i = 0; i < params_node["pose"].size(); i++)
  {
    pose[i] = params_node["pose"][i].as<double>();
  }
  
  std::cout << "yaml: " << params_node << std::endl;
  /
  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("extrinsic", 10);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  
  int count = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  { 
     
    std_msgs::String msg;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << params_node ;
    msg.data = ss.str();

    ROS_INFO("%s", msg.data.c_str());

    /**
    * The publish() function is how you send messages. The parameter
    * is the message object. The type of this object must agree with the type
    * given as a template parameter to the advertise<>() call, as was done
    * in the constructor above.
    */
    chatter_pub.publish(msg);
 
    ros::spinOnce();

    loop_rate.sleep();
    ++count;
  }     
    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try to always post text as text, instead of images of text.

Comment: It is the same. Data is published like you expect it, but rostopic echo shows it as a string. This includes the escaped characters then. In simple words: Its the same data shown in different ways.